# Factory reset a device - settings app does not work

Tags: factory-reset, arnova-gbook

How can I factory reset my Arnova GBOOK tablet/e-reader?

It runs android, and now everything force closes when the device boots, inluding the settings and launcher applications.

I need to use my device - I only bought it today.

Please can someone tell me how I can get my device back? I think resetting may help...

So - how do I reset without the settings app???

Comment: if you just bought it, it should all be covered by warranty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the factory-reset instructions for a device with this specific name. Arnova's devices are named in confusing ways, so perhaps several names are used for the same device in different markets. But can you find a **pinhole** somewhere at the botton of your device? It should be on the left. Does it say "reset"? Then insert a paperclip and see what happens.

If that doesn't work, you could try the instructions on [Arnova's support page](http://arnovatech.com/support/faqs/en/faq_arnova_g3.html?country=lu&lang=en#category_8):

> "If your tablet freezes often or if you get error messages during the start up of your tablet, you can use the recovery mode to reset your tablet to its factory settings, removing all installed applications as well as any data or content.
>
> Your tablet must be up to date with the latest firmware – downloadable from the downloads area of this website.

---

> To access Recovery mode on the **ARNOVA 10bG3**
>
> To access to the recovery mode:
>
> 1. Hold down the volume button + and press the ON/OFF button.
> 2. Once the boot logo ARNOVA is displayed, release the volume button +.
>
> The ANDROID green robot is displayed.
>
> 1. Once the ANDROID green robot is displayed, press simultaneously the volume button + and the ON/OFF button.
>
> The Android system recovery screen is displayed.
>
> a. Use the volume buttons to navigate
>
> b. Use the ON/OFF button to select an option
>
> To restore the default parameters of your tablet:
>
> 1. In the Android system recovery, select Wipe data/factory reset;
> 2. Select Yes –delete all user data.
> 3. Select Reboot system now.
>
> Your tablet reboots. Redefine your parameters through the wizard.
>
> Your tablet is restored to its default settings.

---

> To access Recovery mode on the **ARNOVA 9G3**
>
> To access to the recovery mode:
>
> 1. Hold down the Home button and press the ON/OFF button.
> 2. Once the ARNOVA boot logo is displayed, release the Home button.
>
> The ANDROID green robot is displayed.
>
> 1. Once the ANDROID green robot is displayed, press simultaneously the volume button + and the ON/OFF button.
>
> The Android system recovery screen is displayed.
>
> a. Use the volume buttons to navigate
>
> b. Use the ON/OFF button to select an option
>
> To restore the default parameters of your tablet:
>
> 1. In the Android system recovery, select Wipe data/factory reset;
> 2. Select Yes –delete all user data.
> 3. Select Reboot system now.
>
> Your tablet reboots. Redefine your parameters through the wizard.
>
> Your tablet is restored to its default settings.

---

> To access Recovery mode on the **ARNOVA 8cG3/8bG3**
>
> To access to the recovery mode:
>
> 1. Hold down the volume button – and press the ON/OFF button.
> 2. Once the boot logo ARNOVA is displayed, release the volume button –.
>
> The ANDROID green robot is displayed.
>
> 1. Once the ANDROID green robot is displayed, press simultaneously the volume button + and the ON/OFF button.
>
> The Android system recovery screen is displayed.
>
> a. Use the volume buttons to navigate
>
> b. Use the ON/OFF button to select an option"

Comment: I could, but you would do well to notice that my device is not listed. As such,  none of those combinations work.

Comment: @liamwli: Have you tried them? The problem is that Arnova's naming conventions seem a bit confusing, so the same device could be sold under different names in different markets. And the same method may work for several devices, since they have so many. But I have added another method that may apply to your device (pinhole), see above.

Comment: Hi, I finally managed to get to recovery! Power and Vol + until recovery loads :)

Comment: @liamwli: See? I'm glad you got it to work!